# Database Random to many to many

Tags: sql-server, database, random, relationship

I am a newbie.
I have a table1 that stores User_id 's and another table2 that stores data_id's
Data_id's will be selected random from table2 and all the user_id's should have all the random data_id.

```
                          table1                table2    
                          user1                 data1
                          user2                 data2
                          user3                 data3
                          user4                 data4
                          user5                 data5
```

I want to get 3 random data from table2 and write these data's with user_id's to table3
it should look like below

```
                                  table3
                              user1   data2                                                     
                              user1   data3
                              user1   data4  
                              user2   data2                                                     
                              user2   data3
                              user2   data4     
                              user3   data2                                                     
                              user3   data3
                              user3   data4  
                              user4   data2                                                     
                              user4   data3
                              user4   data4  
                              user5   data2                                                     
                              user5   data3
                              user5   data4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basing @Dan Guzman answer i took it has reference and re modified the answer.If it works fine for you just check and let me know

```
declare @table1 TABLE  ( user_id varchar(10) NOT NULL )
INSERT  INTO @table1
VALUES  ( 'user1' )
    ,   ( 'user2' )
    ,   ( 'user3' )
    ,   ( 'user4' )
    ,   ( 'user5' );
declare @table2 TABLE ( data_id varchar(10) NOT NULL );
INSERT  INTO @table2
VALUES  ( 'data1' )
    ,   ( 'data2' )
    ,   ( 'data3' )
    ,   ( 'data4' )
    ,   ( 'data5' );
;with cte as (
SELECT  user_id
      , data_id
FROM    @table1
        , ( SELECT TOP ( 4 )
                                data_id
                      FROM      @table2
                      ORDER BY data_id
                    ) AS table2
) 
  Select A.user_id,A.data_id from (    
 select   c.user_id,
          c.data_id,
          ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY c.user_id ORDER BY c.user_id,c.data_id) RN
 from cte C  

 )A
     where A.Rn <> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the same 3 random data_id values for each user, one method is with `CROSS APPLY`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.table1 ( user_id varchar(10) NOT NULL )
INSERT  INTO dbo.table1
VALUES  ( 'user1' )
    ,   ( 'user2' )
    ,   ( 'user3' )
    ,   ( 'user4' )
    ,   ( 'user5' );
CREATE TABLE dbo.table2 ( data_id varchar(10) NOT NULL );
INSERT  INTO dbo.table2
VALUES  ( 'data1' )
    ,   ( 'data2' )
    ,   ( 'data3' )
    ,   ( 'data4' )
    ,   ( 'data5' );

SELECT  user_id
      , data_id
FROM    dbo.table1
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP ( 3 )
                                data_id
                      FROM      dbo.table2
                      ORDER BY  NEWID()
                    ) AS table2
ORDER BY user_id
      , data_id;
```

Comment: by giving new_ID() pattern of the data has been changing every time we are executing and Cross apply  not giving exact results @Dan Guzman

Comment: Are you saying you want random values that don't change every time the query is run?  I understood you would use the query to insert the results into table3, where the assigned values wouldn't change.